# К какому тропу можно отнести сочетание "воевать с лесом" и почему?

Tags: лексика, тропы

> (9)В ту же минуту высоко в воздухе раздался захлёбывающийся свист, и в
> рощице, откуда только что выехали танки, с отвратительным кряканьем и
> треском стали рваться тяжёлые немецкие мины. (10)Исковерканные стволы
> осин, ветки, щепки, куски коры летели во все стороны. (11)Снег в роще
> был покрыт паутиной упавших сучьев. (12)Но немцы опоздали. (13)Роща
> была пуста. (14)Немцы яростно воевали с деревьями.
> *(26 задание)*

14 предложение, по мнению составителей задания, содержит троп - иронию.
Это на самом деле так? И как она выражается и какую форму имеет? Просто не совсем осознаю полного понимания этого термина (иронии) и часто ассоциирую с чем-то противоречивым ("Погода хорошая!" - погода плохая), чем, наверняка, сужаю свое понимание об иронии.

Спасибо за ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Иро́ния  — сатирический приём, в котором истинный смысл скрыт или противоречит (противопоставляется) явному смыслу; вид тропа: выражающее **насмешку лукавое иносказание**, когда в контексте речи слова употребляются в смысле, противоположном их буквальному значению.

В данном тексте отчётливо видна насмешка над немцами.